# Trucecrypt one contaner on another

Tags: truecrypt

What is more secure? To use one container encrypted with AES>Twofish>Serpent = 768bits key size
or to make an AES container and inside it make another container encrypted with Twofish and finally inside that container make third container encrypted with Serpent?

What is more secure and whats is faster? Would both ways be 30 Megabits/sec?

Comment: It depends on your CPU.

Comment: Probably better fit in the http://security.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Why not test it yourself?

Comment: @ Nettogrof  , thanks http://security.stackexchange.com/ didnt know that there is more sites :)

Answer (score 2):

Technically, using one container encrypted as AES->Twofish->Serpent would be faster since the Trucrypt program (and the operating system, for that matter) only has to interface with one file and not three.

You also don't have to open one file, then the second, and then the third so it would also be faster from a workflow standpoint.